# Services that just return your public IP as text

Tags: dns, ip, ruby, dynamic-ip, dynamic-dns

I'm writing a script that does dynamic DNS updates for me, but my server is behind a router, and so I need to use a web service to determine my public IP.

So far I've found [this](http://myip.dnsdynamic.com/) one which returns just your plain IP. I was looking around trying to find a couple of alternatives to use in my script supposing that that one is down, but I can't find any others that return just the IP as plaintext.

[These](http://checkip.dyndns.com/) [ones](http://checkip.dyndns.org/) return some HTML, but I really don't want to bother parsing HTML when what the script needs to do is such a simple task.

Does anyone know of some other reliable services which return *only* your public IP in plaintext?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Famous one – [I can haz IP](http://icanhazip.com/):

```
$ curl icanhazip.com
1.2.3.4
```

And that's it.

Comment: True. It's actually the first one I really remember.

Comment: icanhazip.com is not very reliable. Once every few times, the site doesn't answer at all.

Comment: I have to second the unreliability of icanhazip. Some time ago the service also migrated to CloudFlare which sometimes presents a captcha.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't provide direct IP access (for times when your DNS server is down). Other than that, a great service!

Answer (score 18):

I use http://checkip.amazonaws.com/

```
curl -s http://checkip.amazonaws.com/
```

(This form miscounts the above 82 characters as 15 characters, so I have to enter an extra sentence.)

Comment: I had to stop using this service last week, possibly because my ISP started doing something weird.  Now I use http://ipinfo.io/ip , which is free to use for up to 1k queries/day; see http://ipinfo.io/developers .

Answer (score 6):

Or you could host your own. Use a free hosting company, and using PHP use a code like this:

```
<?php

echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

?>
```

Comment: Of course I could do that, but surely there must already be plenty of services out there which do this already.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! Maybe I don't want some one else logging my IPs or spamming some other log

Comment: 'free hosting' will most likely be logging something

Answer (score 5):

see page http://wtfismyip.com, http://wtfismyip.com/text actually on. Get ip address in the form of text. XML or JSON formats too.

or get http://checkip.dyndns.com/ but format is "Current IP Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

Comment: Well thank F@ck for that!